# Newbie - GridView inside tablayout: this/getApplicationContext cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android, android-gridview, android-tablayout

I'm new to android and I'm facing a problem.

Following an example found in android guide, I start playing with tab layout. All work fine until I try to inflate gridview inside "public static class PlaceholderFragment".
Below, a partial copy of the code in MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "MainActivity onCreate End", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

The adapter:

```
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "TAB 1";
            case 1:
                return "TAB 2";
            case 2:
                return "TAB 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And the placeholder, that contain the error:

```
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {

        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Identificativo del TAB che si sta per visualizzare
        int tab_ID = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

        View rootView;
        switch(tab_ID){
            case 1: rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
                    break;
            case 2: rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container, false);
                    break;
            case 3: rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab3, container, false);
                    GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview3);
                    gridView.setAdapter(new MyGridAdapter(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext()));
                    break;

            default:rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container, false);
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Line `gridView.setAdapter(new MyGridAdapter(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext()));` generate "this cannot be referenced from a static context" error.

MyGridAdapter code:

```
private class MyGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public MyAdapter(Context context)
{
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    items.add(new Item("Image 1", Color.GREEN));
    items.add(new Item("Image 2", Color.RED));
    items.add(new Item("Image 3", Color.BLUE));
    items.add(new Item("Image 4", Color.GRAY));
    items.add(new Item("Image 5", Color.YELLOW));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i)
{
    return items.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i)
{
    return items.get(i).colorId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    View v = view;
    ImageView picture;
    TextView name;

    if(v == null)
    {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, viewGroup, false);
        v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
        v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
    }

    picture = (ImageView)v.getTag(R.id.picture);
    name = (TextView)v.getTag(R.id.text);

    Item item = (Item)getItem(i);

    picture.setBackgroundColor(item.colorId);
    name.setText(item.name);

    return v;
}

private class Item
{
    final String name;
    final int colorId;

    Item(String name, int drawableId)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.colorId = drawableId;
    }
}
```

}

I try to follow some other examples without having success.
If i do not declare PlaceholderFragment class as static I have problem with `PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)` in SectionPagerAdapter class.

Could someone help me to solve and understand this problem ?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Remove static modifier from PlaceholderFragment

Comment: and simply use getActivity() in fragment to get context

Comment: gridView.setAdapter(new MyGridAdapter(getActivity()); do not work.. moreover, removing static from class declaration cause problem with PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1) in  SectionsPagerAdapter class

Answer (score 0):

In Fragments you can get the activity by invoking the getActivity() method. Once you have the activity object, you can get the application context by getAtivity().getApplicaionContext();

```
gridView.setAdapter(new MyGridAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
```

Comment: Tanks but, with this code, I get the error: MyAdapter(context) in MyGridAdapter cannot be applied to android.content.Context

Comment: Depends on what parameter MyGridAdapter class constructor takes. Can you paste the code for the constructor? Also you can remove the class as static, as long as you keep the newInstance() method static, it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I update the post with MyGridAdapter class code. If I remove static from class PlaceholderFragment, I have a problem with "PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment" : cannot be referenced from a static context...

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]
Bad code was:

```
            case 3: rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab3, container, false);
                GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview3);
                gridView.setAdapter(new MyGridAdapter(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext()));
                break;
```

OK code is:

```
                    GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview3);
                    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(gridView.getContext()));
```

Thanks!